# How can i use substring query in MySql? I am not getting the values back using substr in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Please find the below query of MySql:

```
    @v_CCommentID=2277,2278,;
    set @v_value1 = SUBSTR(@v_CCommentID, 0, 0);
    select @v_value1; // empty result is displaying.
```

How to get the value of @v_value1 as 2277?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `SUBSTR` method the second parameter needs to set `1` instead of `0`, and your third parameter needs to set how many char you need to get.

> SUBSTR(string, start, length)

use `POSITION` get the `,` comma char position then substring.

```
select @v_CCommentID:='2277,2278';
select @v_value1:= SUBSTR('2277,2278', 1, POSITION(',' in @v_CCommentID) - 1);
select @v_value1;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://rextester.com/ZIV79234)

Comment: Suppose, `WHILE LOCATE(',', v_CCommentID, v_Position1+1)>0
 DO   
select @v_value1:= SUBSTR('2277,2278', 1, POSITION(',' in @v_CCommentID) - 1);
select @v_value1; END WHILE; `
How to get both the value one after another?

Comment: Hi, i am not getting the value of the above one can you help me to come out of this one?